# Cast exception?

Tags: java, nodes, binary-search-tree, classcastexception

So im getting this `ClassCastException` when trying to cast my `Node<T>` to my `AVLNode<T>`. No idea why.

Here is where it throws an exception.

```
Node<Integer> n1 = new Node<Integer>(3, null);
    AVLNode<Integer> n2 = (AVLNode<Integer>) n1;
```

How the classes look...

```
public class Node<T extends Comparable<T>> {

public Node<T> right;

public Node<T> left;

public Node<T> parent;

public T data;

public Node(T data, Node<T> parent) {
    this.data = data;
    this.parent = parent;
} // ...
```

And the other class in separate file:

```
public class AVLNode<T extends Comparable<T>> extends Node<T> {

public int height = 1;

public AVLNode(T data, Node<T> parent) {
    super(data, parent);
} //...
```

Error message:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: custom.trees.Node cannot be cast to custom.trees.AVLNode

Comment: What is the **exact** stacktrace from the exception? For future reference, **always** post the **full** stacktrace if you are asking for help on an exception.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: custom.trees.Node cannot be cast to custom.trees.AVLNode

Comment: Please **update your question** with relevant information. Don't just place it in the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your node is a *SuperClass* of `AVLNode`. You have misunderstood how Java casting works, 
you cannot make such casts as such. The only situation where you should cast is, 
if you have a node reference that points to `AVLnode` Object, you can say

```
Node n1=new AVLNode();
AVLNode n2=(AVLNode)n1;
```

where, since the object type is the same, the reference can be casted.

What you are trying here is to cast a Node (parent class) Object's Reference to a AVLNode (Sub-Class) reference, which simply isn’t possible!

Answer (score 6):

Basically, because a `Node` is not a `AVLNode` - you created it a `Node`, so it's a `Node`. If you'd created it as a `AVLNode` you could cast it to a `Node`, but not the other way round.

Comment: so how come that it works here: https://code.google.com/p/java-algorithms-implementation/source/browse/src/com/jwetherell/algorithms/data_structures/AVLTree.java

Look at the addValue() method.

Comment: thats because the instance returned by super.addValue(id) is an instance of an AVLNode

Answer (score 2):

You are down casting `Node` to `AVLNode`. Since `n1` is an instance of `Node` it does not contain the extra implementation provided by `AVLNode` and this is why you get the casting exception to prevent you from executing a method of `AVLNode` on a `Node` instance.

Comment: Basically this could be a compile error since no assignment to n1 has been made between the two lines